# What does "user $to unknown on host $smtp" mean in Perl's Mail::Sender?

Tags: perl

I'm using Mail::Sender to send mail from Perl. I have a valid SMTP server (it works if I do a telnet). However, I get an error -6 on a MailMsg. The doc shows -6 as

> local user $to unknown on host $smtp

What does this mean? Is it unable to locate the receiver?

```
my $rec=(new Mail::Sender)->MailMsg(
    {smtp=>'smtp.example.net',
     from =>'abc@example.com', 
     to => 'def@example.com', 
     msg => 'Hello'});
```

Comment: can you some code, how you are sending message via `Mail::Sender`

Comment: Why are you using Mail::Sender instead of one of the Email::* modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see the [AUTHENTICATION part of the documentation of `Mail::Sender`](http://p3rl.org/Mail::Sender#AUTHENTICATION), it states that:

> If you get a "Local user "xxx@yyy.com" unknown on host "zzz"" message
>   it usualy means that your mail server is set up to forbid mail relay.
>   That is it only accepts messages to or from a local user.
>   If you need to be able to send a message with both the sender's and recipient's
>   address remote, you need to somehow authenticate to the server.
>   You may need the help of the mail server's administrator to find out what username
>   and password and/or what authentication protocol are you supposed to use.

Comment: but I am a local user and I send to another local user. Why should that be a problem?

Comment: have you read the documentation(Authentication Part) of `Mail::Sender`?

Comment: I did. It says you need authentication for remote users. My to and from are not remote

Comment: I think you need to check the config file, because as you are saying `to` and `from` are local user, that means server are not recognizing them as local. so check it.

Comment: Just because you are a local user sending to a user on the same machine doesn't mean your mailer is going to skip that check. It's going through the same process to send *any* mail. Talk to your network admins to find out what you need to do to send mail.